# How to Reset Value of Ajax NumericUpDown into Minimum value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

The title say's it all how to Reset Value of Ajax NumericUpDown into Minimum value
through C# or Javascript?

Let me say I have ajax NumericUpDown and Button If I click Button named Reset the value of NumericUpDown will reset into minimum value.

```
asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                                     <ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="numeric"  RefValues="" ServiceDownMethod=""
                                         ServiceUpMethod="" Tag="" TargetButtonDownID=""
                                         TargetButtonUpID="" TargetControlID="TextBox1" Width="60" Minimum="1" Maximum="10" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender>

<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" Text="Reset"/>
```

Comment: works <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" Text="Reset" OnClientClick="document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = '1';"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" Text="Reset" OnClientClick="document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = '1';"/>
```

*Pay attention on the Element ID, sometimes .NET changes the client side name

Comment: In order to make the ID not change client-side, you can add the attribute `ClientIdMode` and set it to `Static`